# Give a proper sub-domain to APIGateway with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have an APIGateway working, with some lambda function supportng it and all the rest working.

Now I need to lock the APIGateway to my domain. Imagine that I have the domain www.example.com and I would like that all calls to foobar.example.com end on my APIGateway.

What resources do I need to create with CloudFormation in order to get this?

Example template will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom domain with **foobar.example.com** on API Gateway via CLI or SDK or Console since CloudFormation doesn't support it at this moment. Then you can create a base path mapping for your custom domain in your CloudFormation template.

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping",
  "Properties" : {
    "BasePath" : String,
    "DomainName" : String,
    "RestApiId" : String,
    "Stage" : String
  }
}
```

Comment: And what about the Route53 A-record alias with CloudFormation? Do you have an example?

Comment: I am not sure what example you want, but here is the [CloudFormation documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html) that related to Route53 record.

Comment: I just had problems with `RecordSet.AliasTarget.DNSName` because I set it to the real domain name instead of `xxxx.cloudfront.net`. But now everything is ok